# Upsert with optimistic locking with DynamoDB and Boto3

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to implement an upsert of an item into DynamoDB with optimistic locking. I have the update portion working with a `ConditionExpression` to check the version. But this fails the save portion as the `ConditionExpression` is false for saving. Is it possible to write the `ConditionExpression` so that it will handle both situations?

My code:

```
result = copy.copy(user)
table = get_db_table()

current_version = result.get_version()
result.update_version()

try:
    table.put_item(
        Item=result.to_table_item(),
        ConditionExpression=Attr(result.get_version_key()).eq(current_version)
    )
except ClientError as error:
    logger.error(
        "Saving to db failed with '%s'",
        str(error))
    # Restore version
    result.set_version(current_version)
    raise Exception(ErrorCode.DB_SAVE) from error
return result
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need to make sure the attribute exists before you can compare something to it. Your condition expression string should be

```
does_not_exist(current_version) or current_version = expected_current_version
```

Using Boto3, you can create this using

```
Attr(result.get_version_key()).not_exists() | Attr(result.get_version_key().eq(current_version))
```

Comment: I used: `Attr(result.get_version_key()).not_exists() | Attr(result.get_version_key()).eq(current_version)`. If you update your answer, I will accept it.